# OffsetDateTime.now() requires API 26

Tags: java, android

I need to use method `setStartTimestamp(OffsetDateTime startTimestamp)` but my minSdk is 21 so it shows me `Call requires API level 26`. Is there any way how can I use OffsetDateTime on lower apis?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use **Java 8+ API desugaring support (Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0+)**

It is described in [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support)

Simply you have to modify your build.gradle file in your app module like this:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // Required when setting minSdkVersion to 20 or lower
    multiDexEnabled true
  }

  compileOptions {
    // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}

dependencies {
  coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9'
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`java.time` APIs on Android require API 26.

For older API levels you can use [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) which is the Android version of JSR-310 `java.time` backport for Java 6.