# org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException

Tags: android, date, kotlin, date-parsing, threetenabp

```
val dateFormatter= DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
        .toFormatter()  

val begin = (LocalDateTime.parse("2019-11-04", dateFormatter).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                    .toInstant()).atZone(ZoneId.of(timeZoneIdentifier))
```

When I try to parse the date like this, i get the following error:

***Text '2019-11-04' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: DateTimeBuilder[, ISO, null, 2019-11-04, null], type org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeBuilder***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor when parsing LocalDateTime (Java 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454025/unable-to-obtain-localdatetime-from-temporalaccessor-when-parsing-localdatetime)

Answer (score 0):

use `LocalDate` instead `LocalDateTime`, Like this:

```
val begin = (LocalDate.parse("2019-11-04", dateFormatter).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                .toInstant()).atZone(ZoneId.of(timeZoneIdentifier))
```

But this call require min api 26. For olders APIs, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49348967/9392134)

Comment: I can’t compile it. I get *The method atOffset(ZoneOffset) is undefined for the type LocalDate*.

Answer (score 0):

Since `2019-11-04` is ISO 8601 format and `LocalDate` and the other java.time classes parse ISO 8601 format as their default, you don’t need any explicit formatter. Just this:

```
    val begin = LocalDate.parse("2019-11-04")
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(timeZoneIdentifier))
```

Assuming that `timeZoneIdentifier` is `Europe/Bucharest` the result is a `ZonedDateTime` of `2019-11-04T02:00+02:00[Europe/Bucharest]`.

You cannot parse your string into a `LocalDateTime`. That would require not only a date but also a time of day, and as you know, your string contains only the former.

**Link:** [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)